# Grab the entire QTextEdit into QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qtextedit

I am trying to  grab the entire QTextEdit widget into QPainter using the following code:

```
QTextEdit *textEdit;
QPainter painter;
textEdit->render(&painter);
painter->restore();
```

[image]
This is the what I was able to grab.But, I would like to grab the hidden part of the widget as well into Qpainter. Any suggestions?

Comment: "the entire" and "without the scrollBar" are at odds... the scrollbar is part of the entire widget.

Comment: I might try to grab the viewport only, i.e. `textEdit->viewport()->render(&painter);`

Comment: The problem that I had is when I try to render, only part of the widget is rendered. It doesn't grab the entire widget.

Comment: I have the same issue using viewport as well.

Comment: for "hidden part of the widget" you mean the text that is not shown because of scrolling?

Comment: yes, also if possible the frame of the widget as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save content to image, you need to use [`QTextDocument::drawContents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#drawContents). Something like this:

```
QImage img;
QPainter p( &img );
auto doc = textEdit->document();
doc->drawContents( &p, textEdit->viewport()->size() );
```